# Symfony 2/Sylius - Bundle loaded in AppKernel but can't load resource

Tags: symfony, annotations, sylius

I've generated a bundle (`@ShopfishApiBundle`) using `generate:bundle` like I have many times. It has automatically registered the bundle in the`AppKernel` and it added the loading of the bundle's `routing.yml` to the `app/Resource/config/routing.yml` as well. This is within a `Sylius` installation running `Symfony 2.3`

The `@ShopfishApiBundle/Resource/config/routing.yml` looks like this:

```
shopfish_api:
    resource: "@ShopfishApiBundle/Controller/ProductController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

The product controller looks like this:

```
namespace Shopfish\Bundle\ApiBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

/**
 * @Route("/api")
 */    
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/products")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     *
     * @Rest\View
     */
    public function allAction()
    {
        $products = array();

        return array('products' => $products);
    }
}
```

Loading any page instantly yields the below exception:

```
FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot load resource "@ShopfishApiBundle/Controller/". Make sure the "ShopfishApiBundle" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class.
```

In another Symfony2 (version 2.4) application I've made a similar bundle and this worked without error, I'm thinking something in Sylius messes this up. Do you know where I might solve this issue?

NOTE: I did a little test to see if a direct-no-annotations code snippet worked, and that seems to work. Though I want to use the FOS Rest bundle, using Annotations for Routing.

```
sf_api_controller:
    pattern: /no-annotation-test
    defaults:
         _controller: ShopfishApiBundle:Product:all
```

Comment: Can you post the content of your `AppKernel.php` ?

Comment: Have you also loaded the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle?

Comment: Nope I indeed had not, I had no idea it was required for importing annotated routes in controllers. Thanks for the golden tip!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hadn't registered the essential `SensionFrameworkExtraBundle` in my `AppKernel.php`:

`new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle()`

Thanks, @pazi!